# How do I change the number of login attempts in Firebase?

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I am a mobile developer and I am using firebase for my app which have built with Cordova and Ionic framework.
So .. I implemented Firebase Auth functionalities such login/signup, email verification, forgot your password, ...
But I found this message today while logging in with app.

> "We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual
>   activity. Try again later."

How do I change the number of login attempts in Firebase?

Comment: You can't control that behavior especially since it is likely to change. Typically waiting for some time will unlock that device.

Comment: They don't even need to be failures, just logging in via repeatedly restarting your app while testing it will eventually trigger this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change login attempts.
A blocked user can retry after a few minutes.

Firebase SDK will throw errors you attempts like following:

- multiple times wrong password attempts.
- multiple create a new password, anonymous account tries
- multiple password recovery tries

Comment: Can I know where in the documentation this is written? I'm trying to find the official details for how many invalid password attempts, and what is the duration of next re-attempt.