# Firebase login attempt failed , How to Handle it in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

[How do I change the number of login attempts in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157963/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-login-attempts-in-firebase)
With Reference to this link someone on this link say we can't change login attempts of firebase my React Native app crashes when wrong password entered in firebase the app helds and un freezes when i restart it. is there any solution to overcome with this problem?
This is the Code:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => {
        // this.props.navigation.replace('Home')
        UserEmail = this.state.email
        this.GetUser();

      })
        .catch(error => {
          if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
            this.setState({loading:false})
            this.setState({ errormsg: 'Email address does not exist' })
            this.setState({ emodel: true })
            

          }

          else if (error.code === 'auth/wrong-password') {
            this.setState({loading:false})
            this.setState({ errormsg: 'Invalid password' })
            this.setState({ emodel: true })

          }
          else {
            this.setState({loading:false})
            this.setState({ errormsg: error.message })
            this.setState({ emodel: true })
            
          }
        })
    }
```

Comment: you are probably handling the error incorrectly. if you want to show you code, I can take a look.

Comment: @WenW There is the code

Comment: and what's the error? maybe post a screenshot

Comment: Error does not popup on exception just App freezes

Comment: Where are you returning a response?